# In Haskell's xml-conduit, how can I create a node?

Tags: xml, haskell, yesod, xml-conduit

I'm a Haskell beginner. I'm using [xml-conduit](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.9/xml-conduit-1.8.0/Text-XML.html#t:Node) to transform some XML into HTML, [as seen in the Yesod tutorial](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/xml). I have some attributes and some content that I want to make into a node to add it to existing XML. What's the best way to create a Node? I've tried calling `Node`, but it says it's not in scope. I can make a node using `NodeContent "content"`, or using `NodeElement (Element ... )`, but how can I create a node, providing *both* elements and content?

(The Yesod book suggests using Hamlet, but I'd rather not involve Hamlet, since I'm already using Blaze, and don't want to have to learn and maintain too many templating languages.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the constructors and fields for `Node`...

```hs
data Node
    = NodeElement Element
    | NodeInstruction Instruction
    | NodeContent Text
    | NodeComment Text
```

... and `Element`:

```hs
data Element = Element
    { elementName       :: Name
    , elementAttributes :: Map.Map Name Text
    , elementNodes      :: [Node]
    }
```

Note that an `Element` holds a list of `Node`s, and so you can make it hold a `NodeContent`:

```hs
NodeElement $ Element "b" empty [ NodeContent "Title" ]
```

(Cf. [this example](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/xml#xml_xml_hamlet) in the linked tutorial.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. What are the guards doing in that first data structure? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @Jono Those aren't guards. That is [the definition of the `Node` type](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.9/xml-conduit-1.8.0/src/Text.XML.html#Node) (note the `data` keyword), which has four constructors.